# How to implement laravel notifications within one website in database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, notifications

Notifications within laravel website
I'am beginner of laravel framework. So there is no one experienced laravel developers in my town. There are nobody with whom I could discuss or speak about my laravel project. It's my first laravel project. The problem is I don't know, is everything in right way what I am doing? For example, thare are 2 types of users. 1 administrator, others are ordinary users. I would like to make notifications between administrator and ordinary users within  website. If administrator sends message or something, it should send to chosen user.

Now I am writing notification database. And I have notification table, there are message, user_id(to whom I send this notification) in column name data. My questions

1. Is it right way of making notifications within website between administrator and ordinary users? I have just show this notification by selecting user_id from column name data and show this notification in User's profile(to whom sent by administator)?
2. Is it possible to send notifications with question like "Are you ready? Yes No" with clickable buttons Yes No. As I understand I have to create new table with columns message, user_id, status "Yes" or "No", so when user click yes button it will change the status of this message. Is it right way what I have wrote? Can you write me your ideas or logic of realizing this things. I will be grateful to You.

Comment: "There are nobody with whom I could discuss or speak about my laravel project. It's my first laravel project." Find a Slack or Discord group about Laravel where you can, or even user-groups like [`/r/laravel`](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/).